# Angular ng-repeat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angular v1.4.0-beta.4 and need to iterate an array inside a scope like that:

```
$scope.users = {
   name:'PC Admin',
   login:[
      {
         proto:'https',
         user:'admin',
         pass:'foobar'
      },
      {
         proto:'ssh',
         user:'root',
         pass:'strang3'
      }
   ],
   ip:'192.168.1.2'
}
```

I have looked at Angular ng-repeat docs but can't figure it out.
I tried many things the last was like that (html):

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="user in users.login track by $index">
<li>Usuario: {{user.login[$index].user}}<br></li>
<li>Clave: {{user.login[$index].pass}}<br></li>
</ul>
```

But can't show anything. If I show `user.login[0].user` or `user.login[1].pass` it shows ok, but how to iterate to show every data in the array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the resultant html that you are looking for? Your code is nesting `li` inside of `li` and the outer `li` is not closed. This structure doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two things here. Your current item is available as 'user', yet you try to access the outer array by index.

You either have to use

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in users.login track by $index">
<li>Usuario: {{user.user}}<br></li>
<li>Clave: {{user.pass}}<br></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in users.login track by $index">
<li>Usuario: {{users.login[$index].user}}<br></li>
<li>Clave: {{users.login[$index].pass}}<br></li>
</ul>
```

but the second way would rather be a misuse of the ng-repeat directive IMHO.

Comment: Thanks kasoban & Sphaso, as you could see I'm new at Angular, yesterday I spent many hours to figure it, THANKS! Both solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="user in users.login track by $index">
<li>Usuario: {{user.user}}<br></li>
<li>Clave: {{user.pass}}<br></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kasoban & Sphaso, as you could see I'm new at Angular, yesterday I spent many hours to figure it, THANKS! Both solved my issue

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="user in users.login track by $index">
<li>Usuario: {{user.user}}<br></li>
<li>Clave: {{user.pass}}<br></li>
</ul>
```